# Actualización de valores en R

Tags: r

Día por medio me pasan una base con 10.000 (Y creciendo) registros. La base tiene errores que tengo que corregir para posteriormente analizarla y subirla a una aplicación. Los errores no se van a modificar de origen :-(. Les resumo lo que tengo que hacer:

1. Modificar id específicos. No modificar de a uno sino toda una lista de errores.
2. Un típico error es imputar incorrectamente el sexo. En este caso debería para x id modificar el sexo incorrecto por el correcto.

Ejemplo de data frame:

```
mis_clientes <- data.frame(
  "id" = as.character(c(12345678, 87654321, 13579135, 24682468)), 
  "sexo" = c("f", "f", "m", "A") 
)
```

Con este script modifico los ids:

```
mis_clientes %>% mutate(id = recode(id, "12345678" = "12845172", "24682468" = "23222324"))
```

Preguntas:
a. Id está como carácter porque en realidad son valores alfanuméricos. ¿Como se procesaría si fueran solo números?
b. ¿Si quiero modificar el sexo de los ids 12345678 y 24682468 como podría hacerlo?

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Me doy cuenta que `recode` funciona bien con factores y con caracteres, pero cuando el id es numérico entonces los valores que no se remplazan se convierten en `NA`. Una manera de actualizar los valores de un `data.frame` es usar la función de asignación `<-` para sobre escribir un valor en la posición que quieres actualizar. Para identificar la posición que queremos actualizar, nos podemos ayudar de `wich`.

Primero crearemos un data frame como el tuyo pero con el id numérico

```
#El id es númerico
mis_clientes2 <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(12345678, 87654321, 13579135, 24682468), 
  "sexo" = c("f", "f", "m", "A") 
)
```

Ahora seleccionamos los valores de la columna **id** tal que son iguales a los valores que queremos modificar y los actualizamos.

```
mis_clientes2$id[which(mis_clientes2$id%in%c(12345678,24682468))]<-c(12845172, 23222324)
mis_clientes2
        id sexo
1 12845172    f
2 87654321    f
3 13579135    m
4 23222324    A
```

Podemos hacer algo similar para actualizar el sexo. Pero ahora seleccionamos los valores de la columna **sexo** tales que los valores de la columna **id** sean iguales a los que necesitamos modificar. Nota que usamos los valores actualizados en lugar de  12345678 y 24682468.

```
mis_clientes2$sexo[which(mis_clientes2$id%in%c(12845172, 23222324))]<-c("m","f")
mis_clientes2
        id sexo
1 12845172    m
2 87654321    f
3 13579135    m
4 23222324    f
```